# How to show image using css content?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have the following code, the code is showing some info on a page. At the line with content it is showing a text on my website but I want to put an image near that text, it seems so hard for me

```
 {  
    "id": 85,
    "parent": null,
    "created": "2019-02-06",
    "modified": "2019-02-06",
    "content": "Vielen Dank. Funktioniert immernoch perfekt!!!",
    "pings": [],
    "creator": 6,
    "fullname": "LinusKniepmann",
    "profile_picture_url": "./img/ppl/3.jpg",
    "created_by_admin": false,
    "created_by_current_user": false,
    "upvote_count": 3,
    "user_has_upvoted": false,
    "is_new": true
 },
```

So I want to put an image near the

> "content": "Vielen Dank. Funktioniert immernoch perfekt!!!"

Are there any ways to input the image inside the content code?

Comment: This code looks like JSON to me, not HTML or CSS. While browsers might display this data, I don't know that there is a way to style it with CSS.

Comment: Sorry agree with @robartsd we need some context here, how and where is this being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  background-image: url("images/2019-01-10_093A45.jpg");

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  width: 180px; /* Width of your image */
  
  height: 236px;

  top: 100px; /* Customize to your position preference */
  
  left: 100px;
```

Comment: Michelle, this describes the CSS to use with no explanation or how to utilize it. Need to give context.